# Drag something onto Google map markers and popup, is it possible?

Tags: droppable, marker

I would like to do some effect on google map markers but seems I have tried many ways but got  no hope.

Now I have google map and with several markers, fine.  And I would like to make all the markers droppable using jquery's droppable features so that I can drag a small picture into the marker and popup something.

Is that possible??
Alex

Answer (score 0):

OK I found the idea to make it works.
I overlay another layer with id attribute attached then I can freely to use jquery droppable event.
Thanks